# What FireDAC component can be used to replace dbExpress DBXCommand?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, datasnap, dbexpress, firedac

I have a DataSnap Client and a DataSnap Server, made in Delphi XE4. I do use **dbExpress** on it, but i want to change it to **FireDAC**, because, at the moment, i am migrating XE4 to XE5 and FireDAC is one of things that i want to have in my project.

**The problem is that i dont know how to migrate dbExpress to FireDAC**. Does FireDAC have a component similar to dbExpress DBXCommand component?

For example, using that code:

```delphi
function getDataTest(const pint_Integer : integer;
                     const pbol_Boolean : boolean;
                     const p_json       : TjsonObject
                     const pstr_string  : string):TJSONObject;

var
  dbxC : TDBXCommand;
begin

  dbxC := FscDataSnap.DBXConnection.CreateCommand;
  dbxC.CommandType  := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
  dbxC.Text         := 'TdssMethodsTest.getData';
  dbxC.prepare;

  dbxC.Parameters[0].Value.SetInt32(pint_Integer);
  dbxC.Parameters[1].Value.SetBoolean(pbol_Boolean);
  dbxC.Parameters[2].Value.SetJSONValue(p_json,true);
  dbxC.Parameters[3].Value.SetJSONValue(pstr_string);

  dbxC.ExecuteUpdate;

  result := TJSONObject(dbxC.Parameters[4].Value.GetJSONValue);

end;
```

I want to use same commands but using FireDAC.

What FireDAC component can be used to replace dbExpress DBXCommand and use it (the way the code above uses), properly on FireDAC?

**Obs: i really want to use JSON, i need it.**

Comment: Closest I think is the [`TADStoredProc`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=uADCompClient_TADStoredProc.html), but you will need to to modify your code (FireDAC doesn't have direct support for JSON parameter values as far as I know).

Comment: Sure that FireDAC does not have direct support for JSON?? It is newer/better than dbExpress... FireDAC need to have it. The only reason that i am not using TADStoredProc its because it does not have direct support for JSON...

Comment: You can still get that JSON as string and pass it `AsString`, don't you ? I don't believe it would be useful to have this support. I mean, I don't know many people that would need to store, or pass a structured file to a table or stored procedure.

Comment: Yes of course it is useful. I have a DataSnap Server and a DataSnap Web Client(Javascript)(FOR EXAMPLE), the client call methods from DataSnapServer passing JSON's as parameter. Then, the DataSnap Server receives the JSON parameter and do the appropriate treatment, and return another JSON containing data. I cant do it with TADStoredProc in Delphi XE5 Client. Can i?

Comment: Why you cannot transfer JSON using AsString ?

Comment: Because i want to handle the JSON, manipulate the JSON, before sending.

Comment: Ok. But you can always serialize JSON to / deserialize JSON from string.